# Difference between static variables intilization

Tags: java, static, initialization, static-methods

Here is the code which works fine,

```
class Temp6{

public static Hello var1 = haa();

private static Hello haa(){
  Hello ha1 = new Hello();
  return ha1;
}

public static void main(String[] args){}

}

class Hello{
int h = 10;
}
```

This above mentioned code does nothing, it just assigns var1 from a return type of `haa()` method.

I tried the same once again, I don't understand why I get an error, someone could help me to find what's the difference and what's the reason.

Here is the could which results in this error:
`error: <identifier> expected
   var1 = haa();
       ^
  1 error`

Code:

```
class Temp7{

public static Hello var1;
var1 = haa();

private static Hello haa(){
   Hello ha1 = new Hello();
   return ha1;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
}
}

class Hello{
 int h = 10;
}
```

Comment: `var1 = haa();` this statement must be inside some method or block.

Comment: but why is it so?

Comment: Fine I got it,that's a silly mistake, that's the whole reason why static blocks constructors and methods were there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put static initializers in a `static { ... }` block:

```
static {
    var1 = haa();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for initialize static variables in your situation.

**First solution:** Using directly new keyword same line with declare variable.

```
class Temp6 {
   public static Hello var1 = new Hello();
}
```

**Second solution:** put static initializer in static initializer block. Doing this when we need complicated initializer. (calling another methods, prepare some parameters ...)

```
class Temp6 {

   public static Hello var1;

   static {
      var1 = haa();
   }

   private static Hello haa(){
     Hello ha1 = new Hello();
     return ha1;
   }
}
```